# Database of metadata files across multiple directories

Tags: database, metadata, document-oriented-db, nosql

Consider multiple binary files associated with one metadata file each across multiple directories:

```
directory1: file1.bin file1.txt
directory2: file2.bin file2.txt
```

The metadata files contain structered data in XML or JSON format. 
Is there a database which can use these metadata files for operating and running queries on them?
From what I understand about document oriented databases is, that their data files are stored in one directory.

My question is related to [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524302/methods-for-storing-metadata-associated-with-individual-files). Unfortunately, there is no good description on a XML-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get good query performance on metadata based queries, virtually any system will have to extract the metadata from individual metadata files and store in a more optimized form: one or more *index(es)* of some form or other.   If there's associated data only stored in files, and not in the index (like your .bin files), then the index entry would need to store a *path* to to the file it so the associated data can be retrieved when needed.   The path can typically store directories names, machine names, etc.   In modern systems the path could be a URL.

A document oriented database might be a perfectly good place to store the metadata index, but isn't necessarily the best choice.   If the metadata you need to query on is highly regular (always has the same fields, then some other form of index storage could have substantially better performance, but if you don't know ahead of time the structure of the metadata, a document oriented database might be be more flexible.  Another approach might be use of a full-text search engine if you are trying to match words and phrases in the metadata.

So yes, such databasees exist.   Unfortunately, there are far too many factors unspecified to make a specific recommendation.   The question isn't well suited to a generic answer, the size of the document collection, expected transaction rate, required storage and retrieval latency targets and and consistency requirements could all factor into a recommendation, as would might any platform preferences (window vs *nix, on-premise vs cloud, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have to look up, whether I can generate an index from distributed files with one of the standard tools like CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query structured data directly in XML or JSON files there are tools for doing so, for example:

- [xml-grep](http://xml-coreutils.sourceforge.net/xml-grep_man.html)
- [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If your metadata text files relate to interpreting the binary files, I'm not aware of any generic parser for this. One may exist, but it seems a stretch unless you are using well-defined formats.

The general approach of working with these files directly is going to be inefficient if you need to make repeated queries, as any non-database solution is going to involve parsing the files to resolve your queries. A [document-oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) refers to the ability to store structured content, but the on-disk format will be more efficient (and complex) than text files and XML/JSON metadata which has to be parsed.

If you actually want to use a *database* and build appropriate indexes over structured content, you should import your raw data into one.