# Programmatically add/associate metadata to any file

Tags: metadata

I'm building a tool that will export files from a learning management system and store those files somewhere like S3. I need to keep track of certain pieces of information about those files that relate to the system they're coming from (e.g. course name, academic term, student's name/id). The file types will vary drastically, so I don't want to make accommodations to store the metadata based on the filetype (like pdf or doc).

What's the best way to associate filetype-agnostic metadata to a file? I'm toying with the idea of generating a JSON file for every file I bring over, but it would be great if I could add the metadata directly to the file itself.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/524302/1157054